# Symfony: Generate documentation from markdown with Table of contents

Tags: php, symfony, markdown, documentation-generation, symfony-3.2

What are the best practices for generating a documentation (of a tool/service) in Symfony?

To be a little more explicit:

- I want to **use Markdown** to write a documentation
- I will probably have more files (about 5-10 files) with different topics, located in one folder (or maybe even in subfolders)
- In the documentation files I would like to have reference links to other documents
- I would like to automatically generate a complete documentation from that source. This should contain:

  - Table of contents (with links to the headlines of the documentation files)
  - Generated HTML-Files with separate links for all source files

I've already searched the web, but only found those libraries that are only partly satisfying my needs:

- https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMarkdownBundle
- https://github.com/czukowski/markdown-toc

Anybody has any ideas or already use a bundle?

Answer (score 1):

i use phpDocumentor bundle for symfony: https://symfony.com/projects/phpdocumentor

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this is not what I was asking for. I'm not looking for something to document my php-code. I want to document the usage of my tool, which I build with symfony. So it is addressed to the user instead of the developer.